# SwiftUI - Include Relationship info in FetchRequest

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have an Expense entity with a one-to-many relationship to an Accounts Entity.

My current fetch request is as follows:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: Expenses.entity().name ?? "Expenses")     
        
request.predicate = predicate
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
let expression = NSExpressionDescription()
// check operations list from apple or nshipster in nsexpressions
expression.expression =  NSExpression(forFunction: "noindex:", arguments:[NSExpression(forKeyPath: "originAccounts.isCredit")])
expression.name = "checkIsCredit"
expression.expressionResultType = .booleanAttributeType // might be another
        
let expression1 = NSExpressionDescription()
expression1.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "noindex:", arguments:[NSExpression(forKeyPath: "id")])
expression1.name = "checkExpenses"
expression.expressionResultType = .UUIDAttributeType
        
request.propertiesToFetch = [expression,expression1]

context.perform {
    do {
        let results = try request.execute()
        print(results)
```

My Predicate is:

```
predicate: NSPredicate(format: "expenseDate >= %@ AND expenseDate < %@", datesView.prevMonthPayStart as NSDate, datesView.nextPaydate as NSDate)
```

When I print the results I get

```
[{
    expenseAccount = "Test Account";
    expenseCategory = "Test Category";
    expenseCost = 123;
    expenseDate = "2020-11-12 05:00:00 +0000";
    expenseIsPaid = 1;
    expenseName = Test;
    expenseType = "One-time";
    id = "AFB5EB0E-20A2-47EA-8F36-22D07571C213";
    shouldDupe = 1;
}, {
    expenseAccount = "Test Account";
    expenseCategory = "Test Category";
    expenseCost = 23;
    expenseDate = "2020-11-13 05:00:00 +0000";
    expenseIsPaid = 0;
    expenseName = "Test Recurring";
    expenseType = Monthly;
    id = "5CFB5E58-4377-40DA-9C6A-AF8027ACEC60";
    shouldDupe = 1;
}]
```

I understand that I won't see attributes that are nil, but I want to get an attribute through originAccounts relationship. Is this possible? Specifically I want to get the value of originAccounts.isCredit. Here is an example object for reference.

```
<Expenses: 0x60000321af80> (entity: Expenses; id: 0xa7ab05bb9341bf4a <x-coredata://ED302202-3018-445F-8FFE-DD2E85219E64/Expenses/p1>; data: {
    expenseAccount = "Test Account";
    expenseCategory = "Test Category";
    expenseCost = 123;
    expenseDate = "2020-11-12 05:00:00 +0000";
    expenseId = nil;
    expenseIsPaid = 1;
    expenseName = Test;
    expenseType = "One-time";
    id = "AFB5EB0E-20A2-47EA-8F36-22D07571C213";
    lastMonthlyExpenseID = nil;
    nextMonthlyExpenseID = nil;
    originAccounts = "0xa7ab05bb9341bf4e <x-coredata://ED302202-3018-445F-8FFE-DD2E85219E64/Accounts/p1>";
    originCategories = nil;
    shouldDupe = 1;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try NSExpressions, you won't make a fetch, therefore you'll be mutch efficient.

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "yourEntity")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "yourPredicate")
    fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    
    let expression = NSExpressionDescription()
    // check operations list from apple or nshipster in nsexpressions
    expression.expression =  NSExpression(forFunction: "yourOperation", arguments:[NSExpression(forKeyPath: "Expenses.originAccounts.isCredit")])
    expression.name = "yourName"
    expression.expressionResultType = .decimalAttributeType // might be another
    
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [expression]
    
    do {
        let results = try viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print(results)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to fetch aggregates")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This did help get the relationship values, but now I ONLY get the isCredit values. I need to get isCredit AND the other Expenses object info.

Comment: Ok, good, then you should add another expression to the array. let expression2 = .... and then add it to the fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [expression1, expression2]. Please let me know if it works

Comment: Didn't seem to work @Carlos Maria Caraccia. I've included my new expression in the original post since it's hard to format in here. When I add the expression I seem to get an empty dictionary.

Comment: @nastri83 have you tried adding AND to the predicate to get both results?

Comment: I have added my predicate to the original post as well. I have a number of expenses that match the predicate. I may have misspoke when I said it prints an empty dictionary. I receive an array of dictionaries for each object but each dictionary is blank.
Example for 2 objects matching the predicate: ` [{ }, { }]`

Comment: ACTUALLY it looks like propertiesToFetch was key here. I don't need the expression, but I can specify the relationship as part of the propertiesToFetch.
So for example. this works!
      request.propertiesToFetch = ["originAccounts.isCredit","id"]

Thanks so much for your help Carlos!!